# pre-populate associative array keys in awk?

Tags: awk, associative-array

I've written a munin plugin that uses slurm's sacct to monitor job states on a HPC cluster.  I've written it in sh + awk (rather than my usual tool of choice, perl).

The script works, but it took me ages to figure out how to pre-populate the associative array of possible states (some/most may not be present in sacct output, and i want them to default to zero).  Google wasn't much help, and the best I could come up with was to use split on a string to produce a temporary array, which I then iterated over.

I came up with this:

```
BEGIN {
    num = split("cancelled completed completing failed nodefail pending running suspended timeout",statenames," ");
    for (i=1;i<=num;i++) {
        states[statenames[i]] = 0
    }
  }
```

This works, but seems clumsy compared to how i'd do it in perl, like this:

```
foreach (qw(cancelled completed completing failed nodefail pending running suspended timeout)) {
    $states{$_} = 0;
}
```

or this

```
%states = map {$_ => 0} qw(cancelled completed completing failed nodefail pending running suspended timeout);
```

my question is: is there a way of doing this in awk that is similar to either of the perl versions?

[ edited ]

to clarify, here's a sample of the sacct output i'm piping into awk.  Note that the only states in this output are RUNNING, COMPLETED, and CANCELLED - the others don't exist (because they haven't occurred today), but i want them in my script's output anyway (in  a form usable by munin as "statename.value 0").

```
# sacct -X -P -o 'state' -n
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
RUNNING
COMPLETED
RUNNING
COMPLETED
RUNNING
COMPLETED
COMPLETED
CANCELLED by 1000
COMPLETED
```

[ edited again ]

and here's sample output from my munin plugin:

```
# ./slurm-sacct
suspended.value 0
pending.value 0
nodefail.value 0
failed.value 0
running.value 6
completing.value 0
completed.value 5
timeout.value 0
cancelled.value 1
```

The script runs and does what I want, I just wanted to know if there was a better way to initialise the associative array.

Comment: You have it right. Awk does not provide a way to directly init an array with it's indices. It's a philosophical difference between awk and perl - awk deliberately keeps it's language concise so there's no direct way to do things that are trivial with other language constructs, whereas perl gives you a bewildering myriad of language constructs to do things as briefly (but not necessarily concisely) as possible. @DavidZaslavsky has a correct awk answer for you but there's one modification I'd suggest you consider and I'll post a separate answer now since it won't fit in a comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably don't need to do it at all. Variables in awk are dynamic, which means they're automatically initialized when they are first used (either assigned to *or accessed*), and this applies to array elements as well.

A variable will be initialized to 0 if it's accessed in a numeric context, or to the empty string otherwise. (At least gawk does this, though I'm not sure if it's implementation-dependent) So if you're doing something like counting the number of jobs that are in each state, the entire program is as simple as something like

```
{ states[$1]++ }
END {
     for (state in states) print state, states[state]
}
```

Each time the expression `states[$1]++` is executed, it will check for the existence of `states[$1]` and initialize it to 0 if it doesn't already exist.

---

*EDIT*: From your comment I'm guessing you want to print out a line for each possible state, regardless of whether there are any jobs in that state or not. In that case, you need to include all the possible state names, and there is no shortcut notation for doing so as there is in Perl. As far as I know, what you've already found is about as clean as it gets. (Awk is not really designed with that usage in mind)

I'd suggest the following:

```
{ states[$1]++ }
END {
     split("cancelled completed completing failed nodefail pending running suspended timeout",statenames," ");
     for (state in statenames) print state, states[state]+0
}
```

Comment: yes, that's all true but as i said, not all of the states will appear in every execution of sacct - i want them to default to zero, which is why i want to pre-populate the assoc. array keys with all the possible state names.  e.g. usually, the only states that will appear will be 'running', 'completed', 'failed', and 'cancelled'.  unless the array has zero values for the other possible states (keys to the assoc. array), they won't appear in the output.  at least, not without a lot of special-case if/then/else code - far simpler to just init the assoc array with all possible key names.

Comment: POSIX awk will also initialize variables to 0 or the empty string. I think it actually goes all the way back to the original awk.

Comment: OK, sounds like what i had with the BEGIN and yours with the END block are about as good as it's going to get with awk.  The main reason for my question was that I was surprised that google didn't come up with anything directly relevant, so i figured it was either something extremely obvious that i'd missed, or it was just me applying a perlish mindset to awk.

Comment: Anyway, I'll give it a day or so in case someone else comes up with something good, but i think i'll end up accepting this answer for your "...about as clean as it gets..." comment.  i prefer my method, though, because it makes more conceptual sense to me as an initialisation / setup thing so it belongs in a BEGIN block.  thanks, anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps Craig can use instead of :

```
print "Timeout states ",states[timeout],".";
```

this:

```
print "Timeout states ",int(states[timeout]),".";
```

In my case if there is no timeout state in awk input, the first print will give:

> Timeout states .

While the second will give:

> Timeout states 0.

Comment: No need for a call to int(), just use +0 or printf "%d".

Answer (score 1):

I think a more natural approach in awk would be to have a separate file of keys. Consider a file `keys.txt` with one key per line. You could then do something like this:

```
printf "key1\nkey2\nkey2\nkey5" | 
  awk '
    FILENAME == "keys.txt" {
      counts[$0] = 0
      next
    }

    {
      counts[$0]++
    }

    END {
      for (key in counts) {
        print key, counts[key]
      }
    }' keys.txt -
```

With five keys in `keys.txt`, this produces:

```
key1 1
key2 2
key3 0
key4 0
key5 1
```

Although the keys are shown in order here, that's just incidental and shouldn't be relied upon.

For the specific example, you could also skip the associative array altogether. Instead, you could minimally process the lines with awk and use `sort | uniq -c` to tabulate the counts. The presence of all keys could be ensured using `join` against a file of keys.

Comment: the hash is necessary because it's the "cleanest" / simplest way of always getting all the job states listed in my output even when they don't always appear in the input.  which is why i didn't do something simple with sort|uniq|xargs|sed.  and i didn't use perl because I haven't used awk for much beyond simply extracting fields from a tabulated text stream for years and thought it was a good opportunity for some awk practice.

Comment: also, can't say i like the external file idea.  it adds an external dependancy to the script and doesn't do anything to remove the 'clumsiness' of what i came up with (IMO, makes it worse).

Answer (score 0):

awk is somewhat clumsier (I would say "less terse") than Perl.

You could write this (similar to @Michael's answer):

```
pipeline of data |
awk '
  NR == FNR {statenames[$1]=0; next}
  { usual processing }
  END { usual output }
' <(printf "%s\n" cancelled completed completing failed nodefail pending running suspended timeout) -
```

Answer (score 0):

One tweak to @DavidZaslavsky's answer might be to print the states in the order you specified them on the split() line. That would be:

```
{ states[tolower($1)]++ }
END {
     n = split("cancelled completed completing failed nodefail pending running suspended timeout",statenames)
     for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
         state = statenames[i]
         print state, states[state]+0
     }
}
```

I also converted the input to lower case so it matches your hard-coded values, got rid of the unnecessary 3rd arg to split() and the subsequent null statement (trailing semi-colon).

In case you want to account for finding state names in your input that weren't in your hard-coded set, you could tweak it to:

```
{ states[tolower($1)]++ }
END {
     n = split("cancelled completed completing failed nodefail pending running suspended timeout",statenames)
     for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
         state = statenames[i]
         print state, states[state]+0
         delete states[state]
     }
     for (state in states) {
         print "WARNING: found new state name %s\n",state | "cat>&2"
         print state, states[state]+0
     }
}
```